# How can we define the main of nested quantifiers?

Tags: logic

I am so confused with sentences with many nested quantifiers even though I already define the scope of the quantifiers in the sentences:

There is an agent who sells policies only to people who are not insured.

∃x [Agent(x) ∧ ∀y, z (Policy(y) ∧ Sells(x, y, z) ⇒ (Person(z)∧￢Insured(z)))].

I guess the ∃x is ∧ after Agent(x) and ∀y is ⇒ after Sells(x, y, z) but am not sure where the main connective logic of ∀z is? Is it the "∧" connective between Person(z) and ￢Insured(z)?

Comment: use parentheses, to make it easier

Comment: if using it would be like this ∃x Agent(x) ∧ ∀y, z ( Policy(y) ∧ Sells(x, y, z) ⇒ (Person(z)∧￢Insured(z)) )